# Increment and record creation based on field value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Access 2003

Ultimately I need to create a report for printing labels "Sample ID, Jar x of x".

My table has Sample ID and Number of Jars. Is it possible to create a query that gives me 3 fields: Sample ID, Jar Number, Number of Jars - where the Jar Number creates records in increments based on Number of Jars?

```
  Query:  Sample ID - Jar Number - Number of Jars
          Sample 1    1            4
          Sample 1    2            4
          Sample 1    3            4
          Sample 1    4            4
          Sample 2    1            2
          Sample 2    2            2
```

The table information is:

```
  Table:  Sample ID - Number of Jars
          Sample 1    4
          Sample 2    2
```

I want to avoid creating a table record for each jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of a numbers table:

```
SELECT samples.[Sample ID], 
       samples.[Number of Jars], 
       Numbers.Number AS [Jar Number] INTO NewSamples
FROM samples, Numbers
WHERE Numbers.Number<=[Number of Jars]
```

Samples is the name of your current table.

The numbers table contains integers between 1 and what ever number is the highest number you can get for jars, say 100.

If you already have a zero-based numbers table, you could use:

```
WHERE Numbers.Number Between 1 And [Number of Jars]
```