# MS ACCESS insert records base on quantity number

Tags: winforms, ms-access-2010

I have 2 table and the relation is [Booking_Num]

- **table A:** [ID],[Booking_Num] [Prod_Name],[Qty_Order]
- **table B:** [ID],[Booking_Num],[Prod_Name],[Date_Out]

when I get insert to table A, should be the table B get many record base on Qty_Order..?
sample:

```
 table A
 ID | Booking_Num | Prod_Name | Qty_Order | 
 01 | BOK001      | Hammer    | 4         |

 table B
 ID | Booking_Num | Prod_Name | Date_Out |
 01 | BOK001      | Hammer    | Null     | 
 02 | BOK001      | Hammer    | Null     | 
 03 | BOK001      | Hammer    | Null     | 
 04 | BOK001      | Hammer    | Null     |
```

Thanks

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Comment: Microsoft Access (VBA)

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about VBA. But, I think you can open record set and create a loop to insert record as you want.

Comment: Can you create a numbers table? If so, you can use SQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486569/increment-and-record-creation-based-on-field-value/15486634#15486634